# I used Open CV to get the Image Difference using Python and code doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, deep-learning, arguments

I am using Python 3.6.2. I am looking to run this code https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/06/19/image-difference-with-opencv-and-python/, but I have received this error:

usage: [-h] -f FIRST -s SECOND
error: the following arguments are required: -f/--first, -s/--second"

when I run the last line of this code and I don't know what is wrong:

```
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2
import args

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()

ap.add_argument("-f", "--first", required=True,default='I:\Aaron - Satslab\Pyimagesearch - code - Image processing and computer vision and others\image-difference\images\first.png',
    help="firstinputimage")

ap.add_argument("-s", "--second", required=True,default='I:\Aaron - Satslab\Pyimagesearch - code - Image processing and computer vision and others\image-difference\images\second.png',
    help="second")

args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: The "error" is clear. You "should" be running this from a script (e.g., `run.py`) and running it as the message suggests: e.g., `python run.py --first {PATH_TO_IMAGE1} --second {PATH_TO_IMAGE2}`. And please, keep reading the tutorial. Just took a look at it and it seems that you did not even read it, just tried to copy-n-paste the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you added a default value to the arguments you add, but didn't set `required=False`. This means the program will throw an exception when parsing the arguments, unless you invoke it with the actual `-f`/`--first` and `-s`/`--second`.

The solution is to either:

1. Set `required=False` in both `add_argument` calls, since you provide a default. That way, you can call `python my_script.py` and it will use the default provided.
2. Invoke your program by providing the two CLI options: `python my_script. py -f some_file.png -s some_other_file.png`